# Construct the adjacency matrix of a regular network

Tags: algorithm, graph, adjacency-matrix

Excuse me if it seems too simple but I'm trying to construct the adjacency matrix of a regular network, such that the degree of each node be `k` and the number of nodes `N`. Each node is connected to `k/2` of it's nearest neighbours at each side in a ring shape network.There is no loop and multiple edges. For a simple case `N=8` and `k=4` we have:

```
  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 
  1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
  1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
  0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
  1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
  1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

I wrote a code like this:

```
    A (1:n,1:n) = 0
    do j = 1,n
    do i = 1,n
       if ( (i-k/2<=j) .and. (j<=i+k/2) )  A(i,j) = 1
       if ( (j-k/2<=i) .and. (i<=j+k/2) )  A(i,j) = 1
       if (i==j) A(i,j) = 0
    enddo
 enddo
```

the problem is `k`rows of up and down. perhaps a periodic bondary should be applied. 
I searched in many similar questions, however, nothing was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved without any conditions.

The k/2 neighbours for a `vertex x` on one side can be mapped as:

```
A(x , ((x - 1 + 1) % N) + 1) = 1

A(x , ((x - 1 + 2) % N) + 1) = 1
.
.
.so on till k/2 neighbours
```

The k/2 neighbours for a `vertex x` on one the other side can be mapped as:

```
A(x , ((x - 1 + N - 2) % N) + 1) = 1

A(x , ((x - 1 + N - 1) % N) + 1) = 1
.
.
.so on till k/2 neighbours
```